# Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size. (Gradle Minecraft Forge build)

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Trying to simply build forge 1.19.2 with via Gradle and I'm getting weird jvm argument errors, likely due to the gradle.properties jvmargs.

Building:

- forge-1.19.2-43.2.23

With:

- Gradle 7.5.1
- Eclipse Temurin JDK 17.0.8.1+1 (x86 and is TRUE as the selected JDK by Gradle)
- Latest version of Intellij IDEA Community version

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:415)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultJavaExecAction.execute(DefaultJavaExecAction.java:52)
Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.

    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecActionFactory.javaexec(DefaultExecActionFactory.java:195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.javaexec(DefaultProject.java:1161)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.mcp.function.ExecuteFunction.execute(ExecuteFunction.java:127)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.mcp.util.MCPRuntime$Step.execute(MCPRuntime.java:178)
A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The thing is, when I raise the gradle.properties jvmarg to, say, the original 3G, I get a different error entirely:

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
```

The only way I could get it to even start building was to lower the jvmarg down to 512m, but then I'm back at the first error. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm trolling I guess. Silly me knew I was using the x86 instead of the x64 architecture and still saw no red flags (internally) with the jvamargs. For future reference, you need to ensure your JDK is an x64 if your jvmargs require >512m or whatever the cutoff is.

Comment: This is a duplicated answer since there are existing answers for the same issue. Please refer to those instead of adding more duplicates.